# How to write equations with sigma in pyomo

Tags: optimization, pyomo, glpk

I am trying to optimize a micro-grid using pyomo and glpk solver. This is one of my constraint:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_iskeKjYPBPicJDFnZl1QIo275sEq3f9/view?usp=sharing

This is how I wrote it in python:

```
data = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
load = data['L2']
model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
model.i = pyo.RangeSet(0, 23) #i
model.P_w = pyo.Var(model.i, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals) #P-wind
model.P_pv = pyo.Var(model.i, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals) #P-PV
model.P_fc = pyo.Var(model.i, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals) #P-Fuel Cells
model.P_c = pyo.Var(model.i, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals) #P-Charged
model.P_d = pyo.Var(model.i, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals) #P_Discharged
model.UE = pyo.Var(model.i, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals) #Undelivered Energy
model.EG = pyo.Var(model.i, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals) #Excess Generated
def constraint1(model,i):
  return sum(model.P_w[i] + model.P_pv[i]+ model.P_fc[i] + model.P_d[i] + model.UE[i]  for i in model.i) == sum(load[i] + model.P_c[i] + model.EG[i]  for i in model.i)
model.constraint1 = pyo.Constraint(model.i, rule=constraint1)
```

Please excuse the error in indents. However, the values that I am getting are as follows:
*(P_w[0] + P_w[1] +..+P_w[23])+(P_pv[0]+P_pv[1]+..)+....+(UE[0]+UE[1]+...) = (load[0] + load[1]+..) +...*

Whereas the results I want should be as:
*P_w[0]+P_pv[0]+P_fc[0]+..+UE[0] = load[0]+P_c[0]+EG[0]*
*P_w[1]+P_pv[1]+P_fc[1]+..+UE[1] = load[1]+P_c[1]+EG[1]*

I also tried writing:

```
sum(model.P_w[i] + model.P_pv[i]+ model.P_fc[i] + model.P_d[i] + model.UE[i] - load[i] - model.P_c[i] -model.EG[i] for i in model.i) == 0
```

But the answers are the same. How do I formulate it?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't totally clear what you want here.  Your linked math expression is nonsensical / not properly expressed.

It appears you want to make an equivalence constraint "for each i in model.i" and yet you are summing, so just remove the `sum()` statement from both sides of your constraint.  You already have the `model.constraint1()` statement set up to create an individual constraint for each `i` in that set.  So:

```
def constraint1(model, i):
  return model.P_w[i] + model.P_pv[i]+ model.P_fc[i] + model.P_d[i] + model.UE[i] == \
         load[i] + model.P_c[i] + model.EG[i]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. That's how the constraints are. I checked it in a published article. However, regarding the python script, I tried removing the sum and I still get an error